# Adjoint operator, a condition for closed range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two Hilbert spaces and $A\in\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$. Suppose that there's $\beta > 0$ such that
$$\inf_{z\ \in\ \text{Ker}(A)}\|x-z\|\ \leq\ \beta\|A(x)\|,\quad \forall\ x\in X.$$
Show that, $\text{R}(A) = \text{Im}(A)$ is closed.

---

Please, somebody can help with this problem? I tried to prove that $\text{R}(A) = \text{Ker}(A^*)^{\perp}$ in order to show that $\text{R}(A)$ is closed, but I really don't know how I can use the fact of $\text{dist}(x, \text{Ker}(A)) \leq \beta\|A(x)\|$. Please, I need some hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about factoring through $X/\ker A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider well defined linear operator
$$
\hat{A}: X/\operatorname{Ker}(A)\to Y:\hat{x}\mapsto A(x)
$$
[It is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242255/quotient-space-and-continuous-linear-operator) and have the same image as $A$. It is enough to prove that $\hat{A}$ have closed image.

1. Since $X$ is complete and $\operatorname{Ker}(A)$ [is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135791/the-kernel-of-a-continuous-linear-operator-is-a-closed-subspace) then $X/\operatorname{Ker}(A)$ [is complete](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319867/how-to-show-that-quotient-space-x-y-is-complete-when-x-is-banach-space-and/319920#319920). Note that $Y$ is also complete.
2. Inequality in your question preciesly means that $\hat{A}$ is bounded below. Just recall the [definition of the quotient norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_%28linear_algebra%29#Quotient_of_a_Banach_space_by_a_subspace).
3. Any bounded below operator between Banach spaces [have closed range](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237281/banach-space-and-bounded-below-operators).

From $1$, $2$, and $3$ it follows that $\hat{A}$ have closed range, and so does $A$. Note that this proof valid for any Banach spaces. Hilbertability is redundant here.